# Why did this happen in my cocos2d project?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I built the cocos solution in vs2019 and I had 2000 warnings. How do I resolve these?

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUS7j.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings are showing up because of deprecated/unmaintained modules in the game engine code, and a lot of the Cocos 2dx code is not in compliance with C++ best practices and standards.

However, you are free to modify the code of the game engine as per your use case (while adhering to the licenses).